# Account Number Auto generation

Tags: mysql

I new to programming. How do I apply auto generation to the accountNo in accounts table. I tried everything. But I don't know how to get this done. Can anyone explain me.

```
CREATE TABLE accounts(
    accountNo int(100) NOT NULL, // I need this to be auto generated.
    accountType VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    firstName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    lastName VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    birthdate DATE NOT NULL,
    gender VARCHAR(7),
    city VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    street VARCHAR(50),
    cellPhone VARCHAR(10),
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY(accountNo)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```
CREATE TABLE accounts(
        accountNo int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        accountType VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        firstName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        lastName VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
        birthdate VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        gender VARCHAR(7),
        city VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        street VARCHAR(50),
        cellPhone VARCHAR(10),
        CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY(accountNo)
    );
        ALTER TABLE accounts AUTO_INCREMENT = 1001;
```

When you are adding new data to your `accounts` table, `accountNo` will be auto generated.

Answer (score 0):

Make it as an AUTO_INCREMENT:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts(
    accountNo int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    accountType VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    firstName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    lastName VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    birthdate DATE NOT NULL,
    gender VARCHAR(7),
    city VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    street VARCHAR(50),
    cellPhone VARCHAR(10),
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY(accountNo)
);
```

For further informations have a look at this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 0):

declear it AUTO_INCREMENT and you can define PRIMARY KEY like that also. Read manual [auto_increment](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

```
accountNo INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```